# VBA Prevent Text Overflow for Cells in Range

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to prevent text overflow for cells within a specified range using VBA? I haven't been able to find anything online relating to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least **3** ways:

1. use VBA to widen the column
2. use VBA to enable text wrap on the cells
3. use VBA to place content to the immediate right of the cells in question

Answer (score -1):

4. use VBA to put the horizontal alignment to xlFill